# Looping without a collection variable in flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, insert, create-records

I am working on a requirement to create child records based on the field value present in the parent record using flow.
If Obj__c is the parent object and Ch__c is its child object and if count__c is a field in Obj__c holding the number of child records to create, can we achieve this using flow. In flow, can we use a normal variable(instead of collection variable) to loop through for creating records. Thanks.

With Apex it is something like this(assuming Obj__c is passed to the flow):

```
List<Ch__c> childs = new List<Ch__c>();
for(Integer i=1;i<=Obj__c.count__c;i++)
{
   Ch__c c = new Ch__c(Name__c =Obj__c.Val__c);
   childs.add(c);   
}
if(childs.size()>0)
{
   insert childs;
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a collection variable? How would the flow know what to do with a normal variable?  What is this normal variable you're talking about?

Comment: If field__c is a field in Obj__c which has a value say 6, I want to create those many child records.

Comment: What have you tried?  what part of it doesn't work?  please edit your question with more detail about what you've tried.  Sounds like a simple iterator in a loop in the flow

Comment: you'll definitely need a collection variable for the constructed child records; But as Nick says, you can use a Decision Block - Assignment - <back to decision block> to do a counter-based loop